# jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate Skip policy

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using `org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate` for batch updates.
It generally stops updating on any failure.
My concern is, is there any way to implement SkipPolicy with above when there is a batchUpdateException? (Similar to Spring Batch skip exception and process remaining rows)?

Comment: No there isn't as that isn't how batch update works. Use Spring Batch if that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It seems not possible with jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate